# chrome crashes when debugging in a specific file while firefox is OK

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, minidump, google-breakpad

I'm using chrome devtools to debug a JS class file. And it always crashes when I move the mouse to view the value of some variables(almost every function in this file could trigger the crash). While everything is OK when using firefox.
I managed to get the analysis of the crash dump file using the breakpad:

```
Operating system: Mac OS X
                  12.3.0 21E230
CPU: amd64
     family 6 model 142 stepping 9
     4 CPUs

GPU: UNKNOWN

Crash reason:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS / KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS
Crash address: 0x7c
Process uptime: 232 seconds

Thread 0 (crashed)
 0  Google Chrome Framework + 0x4b18125
    rax = 0x0000000000000001   rdx = 0x0000134d00000000
    rcx = 0x000000010fc45ff0   rbx = 0x00007ff7b9961da0
    rsi = 0x00000001068cfa38   rdi = 0x0000000000000000
    rbp = 0x00007ff7b9961580   rsp = 0x00007ff7b99614c0
     r8 = 0x0000134d024b303c    r9 = 0x00007ff7b99613c0
    r10 = 0x0000000000000000   r11 = 0x0000000000000001
    r12 = 0x0000000000000000   r13 = 0x00007ff7b9961d38
    r14 = 0x00007ff7b9961598   r15 = 0x0000000000000001
    rip = 0x000000010b24b125
    Found by: given as instruction pointer in context
```

But I don't know what to do next with the crash reason and address. Any ideas on how to get the content of crash address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine now after I updated Chrome from v105 to v106. Seems like it's a bug from Chrome itself.